# Creating a Checkbox, coping it, and making new checkbox report to new spot

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, I know the title may be confusing, but here is goes.

I have a list of lets say 100 people in the excel spreadsheet, all names are in column A, the check-box is in Column B, and the True or False is hidden in Column C.

I manually created the check-box to in Column B. it reports true or false in Column C.

Is there a way to create check-boxes all the way down the list till the last one, and to have said check-boxes report to their own counterpart in Column C so that the check-box above and below are not corrupted by any other check-box data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert 2 type of controls in your scenario. One is a **Forms Control** and the other is an **ActiveX Control**

**Form Control**

To insert a Form Control, you have to use this code

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes.Add 52.5, 3, 42, 17.25
```

The syntax is

```
 CheckBoxes.Add Cell.Left, Cell.Top, Cell.Width, Cell.Height
```

**ActiveX Control**

To insert an ActiveX Control, you have to use this code

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Link:=False, _
 DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=54, Top:=1.5, Width:=39.75, Height:=11.25
```

So to add any of the control above, you have to use a loop to find the co-ordinates of the cell and then add the checkboxes in the relevant location. For your scenario, I would recommend using Form control so that you can have one piece of code which will run when any of the above check boxes are clicked.

Now how we we ensure that all Checkboxes call the same macro :)

**Hint**: This code creates a checkbox and then assigns a macro to the checkbox.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Shp As Shape

    '~~> Create a Checkbox
    Set Shp = Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes.Add(52.5, 3, 42, 17.25)

    '~~> Assing a macro to it
    Shp.OnAction = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "'!macro_name"
End Sub
```

Ok, the next question. How would the macro know which CheckBox is calling it?

**Hint**: Check what `Application.Caller` does ;) Place code in the macro which is linked with the checkbox.

```
Sub macro_name()
    MsgBox "This macro was called by " & Application.Caller
End Sub
```

HTH and gets you on the right track :)

Sid